# Android implicit intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm writing this code in launch current activity in else condtion, however it **crashes when launching current activity.**

```
SharedPreferences signShared = getSharedPreferences("ZapLukShared",MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedUserId = signShared.getInt("logUser_Id",0); 
sharedOtpVerified = signShared.getBoolean("OtpVerified", false);
if(sharedOtpVerified==false) {          
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivty.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);       
}   
else {         
    Intent i2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainPageActivity.class);
    startActivity(i2);
}
```

Comment: add your crash log

Comment: ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.zapapp/.MainActivity }

Comment: add your android-menifest file in question.

Comment: can we give the current and target activty same in intent??

Comment: nooo, can not do that.

Comment: in my task in else condtion i want navigate to same activty where i am currentluy writing the code

Comment: why you want to do so. as you are in same activity

Comment: if(sharedOtpVerified==true)
     {
      Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainPageActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
     }
    else {
 Intent i=newIntent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
     
 }

Comment: if otp verified i want to go directly to main home page,other wise i have to go to mainpage where iam currently writing the code

Comment: is there any other way to complete my task-http://stackoverflow.com/users/2826147/amit-vaghela

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remain in same activity than you dont need to start intent,

```
SharedPreferences signShared = getSharedPreferences("ZapLukShared",MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedUserId = signShared.getInt("logUser_Id",0); 
sharedOtpVerified = signShared.getBoolean("OtpVerified", false);
if(sharedOtpVerified==false) {          
    //no need to start intent if you want to remain in same activity
}   
else {         
    Intent i2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainPageActivity.class);
    startActivity(i2);
}
```

Comment: i have a doubt regarding imageview getting from server when i post my code it is showing some error in blog .@Amit Vaghela

Comment: ask a new question, firstly try solutions from this site.